# Find in nested structures

Tags: c++, struct

I have following nested / hierarchical structures

```cpp
struct C {
    int idC;
};
struct B {
    int idB;
    std::vector<C> vecC;
};
struct A {
    int idA;
    std::vector<B> vecB;
};
vector<A> inputs;

//Get structure objects
int getStructs(int idC, vector<A> inputs, struct &A, struct &B, struct &C);
```

I would like to find struct `A`, `B`, `C` from the `idC` and `inputs`. What would be the efficient approach to find the structure objects  (`getStructs`) in bottom-up fashion.

Comment: Do you know how to find one `C` (by its value of `idC`) in a `vector<C>`? Do you know how to find that `C` in a `B`? Do you know how to iterate over a `vector<B>`, searching for such a `C`? Where do you have difficulty?

Comment: Now I have a nested for loop, where I iterate over vectors of A, B, C respectively and find the structs when idC==C.idC. I just want to know if there is any efficient way?

Comment: That depends on things you haven't specified. Can you sort `vecC`? Will you call `getStructs` once, or many times? Do you have any information about how the numbers are distributed in these structures? What do you plan to do with these objects once you find them? You have not given us enough information for us to give a definitive answer.

Comment: (1)I can sort vecC. (2)getStructs will be called multiple times. (3)the numbers correspond to database entries which are are unique in all structures (4)once the structures are found I would like to update the other attributes (which are not mentioned here) of structures as per the business logic

Comment: Is your current nested `for` loop a proveable bottle neck? If not then leave as is.

Comment: One current inefficiency is that parameter `inputs` to `getStructs` is passed by value. Prefer passing by `const &` to avoid all those copies of vectors.

Comment: If you're going to call `getStructs` many times, it makes sense to construct a map of `inputs` so that you can find things in O(1) rather than O(n). And I'm not sure how you plan to use those other arguments, but you should probably pass references to *pointers,* rather than references to *objects.* But this now looks like a question better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If your vector is sorted, check out [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) with a custom comparer that compares the `id` value.

Comment: `Now I have a nested for loop, where I iterate over vectors of A, B, C` - please post the code you have right now.